# American Accent Am I saying "were" as "where" in this recording?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent

I am trying to learn American Accent, and I am having a problem when saying **were** and **where**, I made this recording to you. I won't write the test that I have said in order to let you feel if my accent is correct or not.

again, I need the **were** in American accent.

This is the recording, i upload it on many websites.

http://www.filedropper.com/record0003

http://www.megafileupload.com/2zRN/Record_0003.wav

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=20034351737334244042

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native American English speaker, I think your pronunciation of **were** sounds pretty close! Native speakers tend to shorten or minimize "were" and almost pronounce it like "wur" or "wer". You replicate that quite well here.

Some of the other words (years, ago, completely, useless) sound less close to a native accent. But overall, it is very easy to understand what you are saying.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. for the other words you mentioned: I guess that I said *thought* quite well. I studied it. Could you tell me what wrong did I do with the word *thought* ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Upon re-listening to the audio clip, I agree that you said *thought* well. I've edited my answer. Sorry for causing any confusion. :)